# Как принять и обработать canvas на сервере?

Tags: php, html, canvas

Не получается принять на сервере canvas. Он даже не фигурирует в массиве $_POST
HTML

```
<form id="post_form" method="post" action="/post" enctype="multipart/form-data" multiple="multiple">
  <canvas id="img" name="img"  style="width:192px; height:108px" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
  <button type="submit" class="post_btn">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
  echo'<pre>';
  var_dump($_POST);
  echo'</pre>';
```

Вариант с аяксом не интересует. Помогите найти причину или ошибку.

Comment: И не должен фигурировать, потому что canvas не имеет никакого отношения к формам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob()` создаёт объект Blob представляющий
>   изображение, содержащееся в canvas

[ссылка на документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob)
Т.е. сохраняете его в объект, к примеру подпись, после вытягиваете на канвас или формируете из нее картинку. Значит перед отправкой формы вы должны получить объект и отправить в форме уже данные